# Problems with Android Studio (problemas with Java version)

Tags: java, android, flutter

I need some help with this error:

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
• Android SDK at /Users//Library/Android/sdk/
• Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
• Java binary at: bin/java
✗ Cannot execute bin/java to determine the version

what do I need to do to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

try adding this line in your path

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

also, have you accepted android licenses? if not run this command

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

Answer (score 0):

This error typically occurs when the Java binary at the specified path in the error message cannot be found or executed. There are a few steps you can try to resolve this issue:

1. Check the specified path in the error message to ensure it's correct and that the Java binary exists at that location. If it doesn't, you'll need to install the correct version of Java and ensure that it's added to your system's PATH.
2. Make sure that the Java version installed on your system is compatible with the version specified in the error message. The error message states that you need Java version 31.0.0, if you have another version installed you might have to update it.
3. Verify that the Java binary is executable. You can do this by running the command ls -l bin/java in the terminal. If the binary is not executable, you can run the command chmod +x bin/java to make it executable.
4. Try running the command ./gradlew --stacktrace in your project folder, this will give you more information about the error
5. If none of the above steps work, you may need to uninstall and reinstall the Android SDK and/or the Java Development Kit (JDK)
6. In case you are on MacOS, check your JDK version with the command /usr/libexec/java_home -V and ensure that the JDK version is the one you want to use.

If you follow these steps, you should be able to resolve the error and continue with your Android development.